# Samsung Pen text recognition returns errors for german language

Tags: android, samsung-mobile-sdk, pen

I am working on an Android App, that uses the Samsung Pen sdk to recognizes handwritten words.
I worked through the tutorials and got the recognition to work, but when I use the german language instead of korean (which is used in the example) I get errors.
The language is in the list of supported languages, so I don't know where I go wrong.

```
...
List<String> languageList = mTextRecognition.getSupportedLanguage();
 if (textRecognitionList.size() > 0) {
  for (String language : languageList) {
   if (language.equals("de_DE")) {
    mTextRecognition.setLanguage(language);
    break;
   }
  }
 }
...
```

This is the part that sets the language. It is copied from the Samsung sample app, but I use "de_DE" instead of "kor".

When this code is executed I get these errors:

```
02-26 18:34:42.411: E/VIHW_JNI_DEBUG(24631): [ReadDataFile] nErrCode = 3
02-26 18:34:42.411: E/TextRecognition(24631): init error: ret = 3
```

And when I request the recognition I get these errors:

```
02-26 18:35:42.441: E/VIHW_JNI_DEBUG(24631): g_pStrokeData memory is NULL!
02-26 18:35:42.441: E/VITextRecognitionLib(24631): Error Code: -1
```

The same behaviour can be observed for half of the languages that are in the supported languages list.
It is essential for me to support german letters like ä,ö, and ü so I can not just fall back on one of the working languages. I tested this on a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (2014) with Android 4.4.2. I am using the pen SDK version 3.1.4

Is there any Samsung documentation telling me what error 3 might mean?

Is there a way to get the other supported languages (especially german) to work?

Answer (score 0):

As per Samsung support the version 3.1.4 of the Spen SDK has a bug so that the list of supported languages is simply wrong. In that version they only support English, Chinese and Korean.
They say the bug will be fixed with 3.1.5, but that only means that the list of supported languages will be correct. German and other languages will probably be supported by future releases.